# Most efficient way of adding functions to a Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

To add a function to a Backbone Model, I can do one of two things:

```
App.WidgetModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
    sayHello: function(){
        console.log('Hello, I'm a widget');
    }
});
```

...or...

```
App.WidgetModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

App.WidgetModel.prototype.sayHello = function(){
    console.log('Hello, I'm a widget');
};
```

Which is the 'right' way of doing this if I will have thousands of widgets in my app at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the first is more common than the second.

```
App.WidgetModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
    sayHello: function(){
        console.log('Hello, I\'m a widget');
    }
});
App.SomeotherModel = App.Widget.extend({
  sayHello: function () {
    App.Widget.call(this);
    console.log('Hello, I\'m a SomeotherModel');
  };
});
```

Even though you may want to extend a model with things that are not backbone

```
var someObject = {/**/};
_.extend(someObject, App.SomeotherModel);
```

Look for instance at http://backbonejs.org/#Events

If we look at the source the [.extend method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1557) does some other things like fixing the prototype chain for the surrogate models so if you are going to use `Model2 = Model1.extend` and so on it is better to define the methods with extend.

Comment: Thanks.  So does this approach add the function to the model's prototype anyway?  In other words, are  the first and second approaches actually doing exactly the same thing under the hood and are therefore just as efficient as eachother?

Comment: It is actually, the same only that the extend fixes the prototype chain and then add the methods to the prototype of the new object.